# Start DSC Configuration securely (UseSsl) without needing to provide the ComputerName

Tags: ssl, dsc

*TL;DR How do i `start-dscconfiguration` over SSL with multiple nodes?*

DSC supports the ability to provide multiple nodes in a configuration. A common example

```
$configData = @{

     AllNodes = @(
           @{
                NodeName = "COMPUTER1";
                Parameter1 = "Foo";
            },
            @{
                NodeName = "COMPUTER2";
                Parameter1 = "Bar";
            }
     )
}

configuration InstallIIS {

         Node $AllNodes.NodeName {

            WindowsFeature IIS
            {
                Ensure = "Present"
                Name = "Web-Server"
            }
        }
}

$mofs = InstallIIS -ConfigurationData $configData 
Start-DscConfiguration -Path $mofs -Verbose -Wait
```

As you're probably aware, this configuration (that installs IIS) will be applied to both COMPUTER1 and COMPUTER2 (2 mof files will be generated).

By default this example will use WinRM over HTTP. As all good programmers know, you should really consider the HTTPS option; so i am.

Here is the `Start-DscConfiguration` example again, using HTTPS (WinRM) with the `-UseSsl` flag:

```
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("mydomain\mike", (ConvertTo-SecureString "ILikeCatsAlot" -AsPlainText -Force))

    $sessionOptions = New-CimSessionOption -UseSsl #note the -UseSsl

    $computerName = "COMPUTER1" #Oh dear i have to pass the computer name

    $session = New-CimSession -Credential $creds -SessionOption $sessionOptions -ComputerName $computerName

    Start-DscConfiguration -Path $mofs -CimSession $session
```

As you see, i need to supply the `-ComputerName` parameter to the `CimSession` which is no good because i want to apply this configuration to all the nodes. It seems like i've lost the ability to provide multiple nodes in the `$configdata`

With DSC, how do i start a configuration overWinRM (transport:https) without needing to supply a specific computer for the session?

Comment: From [New-CimSessionOption](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590764.aspx), `WsMan encrypts all content that is transmitted over the network. This parameter lets you specify the additional protection ... It is recommended that you use this parameter only when the PacketPrivacy parameter is not specified`.  Why do you want to do this?  And why are you specifying to do it insecurely by saying `-SkipCNCheck` and `-SkipCACheck`?

Comment: You could read the configuration data and create the sessions, then call the `Start-DSCConfiguration` for each session.  Otherwise, the feature you are asking for does not exist.  If you still think the feature of specifying a `CimSessionOptions` to `Start-DSCConfiguration` is needed, I would suggest filing an issue in the [PowerShell User Voice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell)

Comment: @TravisEz13 - the requirement is to use DSC over secure WinRM (HTTPS - 5986 ) rather then the default - HTTP 5985. this seems to be the way to achieve it.

Comment: your suggestion of iterating the configuration is a potential option but i still lose the ability to take advantage of the built in configuration filter e.g. Where / Wait

Comment: WRT to using HTTPS, the requirement is now understood, but the sample is confusing in the following ways.  If you specify `-SkipCNCheck`, you are saying don't validate that the server is what it claims to be.  If you specify `-SkipCACheck`, you are saying don't verify that the Server Certificate is trusted.  Since the data is already encrypted, SSL at this point has no value, so this portion of the sample should be reconsidered.

Comment: @TravisEz13 - absolutely agree with the comment regarding the -Skip arguments. sorry for the confusion, i add these initially to check that the connection was valid. i will be removing these eventually in my true case. The reason this question has come about is because the security team at the company refuse to expose the winrm HTTP port (5985), which is fair enough.

Comment: update: i have now removed both the `-SkipCNCheck` and `-SkipCACheck `attributes from my example.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clarification in the comments, this is not currently a feature supported in Start-DSCConfiguration.  If you would like to suggest the feature to the product team, please file an issue in the [PowerShell User Voice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell)

**Update:** Thanks for filing [this issue](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/17691154-start-dscconfiguration-over-secure-winrm-https) on user voice.

Comment: I'm following up with the WSMAN team if there is a way to set SSL to be the default on the client.  If this can be done, this would have side effects such HTTP not being usable from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to build a DSC Pull server (https or SMB)?  SMB is encrypted (SMBv3 uses AES 256) and very simple (some syntax and renaming is involved).  HTTPS Pull allows for a report server to manage your machines centrally and uses TLS like you have mentioned.